# AWS: Can't retrieve keys in S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I need to grab the contents on one of my buckets. I try to do this using the AWS PHP SDK, but nothing is returned. Here's my code:

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$s3client = S3Client::factory(array('credentials' => array(
                    'key'    => '???????',
                    'secret' => '???????' ), 'region'  => '?????', 'version' => 'latest', ));

try {
    $data = $s3client->getIterator('ListObjects', array("Bucket" => "?????"));
    print_r($data);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Here's the ouput:

```
Generator Object ( )
```

The output I get from that code is showing there's nothing wrong. However, there should be some content. The credentials I use are the same ones I use for uploading objects to the bucket, so I don't think those are bad. Am I missing something? How do I retrieve my buckets keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting the iterator and not the objects. 
To get to the objects you need to use the iterator. Something like:

```
foreach ($data as $object) {
    echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not using listObjects.. Thank you!

Comment: you are using list objects. It's just you are getting back an iterator that you need to use to get to the objects themselves.